# Developing a framework in Java

Tags: java, frameworks, enterprise

I'm looking forward to start developing a new server side enterprise communication framework in Java and I'm wondering if anyone knows a good book on the subject? 
Some best practices and advice would be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please explain _why_ first?

Comment: Yet another framework? Are you sure there is a need?

Comment: It will be (in case of success) a framework for communication between two eDMS. There are no frameworks that would fit the profile, especially since both eDMS are our.

Comment: Is eDMS = Electronic Document Management System? If so, you could look at writing JCA adapters, but then you would know better on whether that is viable.

Comment: Yes, it is. I must say I didn't know about JCA. We will give it a shot. THX!

Comment: I did forget one important aspect - usually the DMS vendors tend to offer JCA adapters. Writing an adapter on your own is therefore a choice that is viable only when you are the vendor of the system itself. I believe systems like Documentum have JCA adapters that can be used by system integrators.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Practical API Design: Confessions of a Java Framework Architect" by Jaroslav Tulach (NetBeans architect) sounds like the best fit you're going to find.

But the best advice on developing new frameworks is: don't. Especially if you have to ask. It's very unlikely that you'll do a better job than all the people who wrote the multitude of frameworks already out there.

Comment: The problem is that there is no framework that fits my needs. Thanks for the book, sounds promising.

Comment: @user459493, not to sound like a prick here, but are you really sure that no framework suits your needs in enterprise communication (presumably, messaging is the right word) ? That topic is more or less well studied, and certainly an existing framework would take care of **most of your** needs.

Comment: Well most it's not enough, we are integrating two eDMS systems, both proprietary. So if you can suggest a framework that could fit the profile I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 4):

"How To Design A Good API and Why it Matters" by Josh Bloch.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw

Answer (score 1):

A couple of recommended books:

- [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Addison-Wesley-Signature/dp/0321127420)
- [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.amazon.com/o/asin/0321200683/ref=nosim/enterpriseint-20)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly your eDMSs should connect which each other, if they are code compatible etc. But this may be helpful for you.

Check [Java Content Repository (JCR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_repository_API_for_Java) standard and [JBoss ModeShape](http://jboss.org/modeshape) as implementation. Most of content (also document) repository software providers are JCR-Compliant, e.g. Alfresco but also other not related with Java.

Instead of writing own framework, just write simple ModeShape JCR connector for your eDMS. Then you can easly do federated DMSes, replication, use existing repository management tools, expose your repos via Web Dav, REST, comunicate with other protocols, and do many many other things with opensourced and commercial tools - your repository just must provide JCR connector.

Comment: They should be fully integrated (2 way communication, document search, etc.), one is written in Java and the other one is in .net. They are both written by us so there is maybe some room for modification of the existing code. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Check also this article http://dev.day.com/content/ddc/blog/2008/01/fudbusting2.html about using JCR outside Java.